# Sql Server log file size doesn't maintain size when full db backup is made

Tags: transactions, sql-server-2012, logfile

I have a SQL Server 2012 database with Simple Recovery Model.
The SQL Log file size was set to 20mb but when a full database backup is made, the size of the file is set back to 1mb.. why is that? is the default behavior?

Answer (score 1):

In simple revovery model the log write has very low rate. So every time you take a full backup the engine figure out log is not critical and shrink it to 1mb.

Comment: But The problem is that we need it big because the large number of transactions in our app. Maybe we need to change the recovery model?

Comment: Yes if you need transaction log change it to full recovery model.